# Who should construct objects in this scenario?

Tags: c++, oop

I have the following class:

```
class PluginLoader
{
public:
    PluginLoader(Logger&, PluginFactory&, ConflictResolver&);
    //Functions.
private:
    //Members and functions
};
```

`Logger`, `PluginFactory` and `ConflictResolver` classes are all interface classes which will be implemented in the application. I create the single `PluginLoader` object at top level in the main program. The `Logger` can be known at that level. But, `PluginFactory` and `ConflictResolver` are only used internally in the `PluginLoader` class. So creating their objects at top level seems ugly. What should I do? I can change the constructor if it is needed though I'd like to keep it the way it is. Any comments are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking and what you're doing. If you don't like Dependency Injection (it looks like that's what you're doing here -- but I could be wrong?), just use the Mediator Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern. I'm not leaving this as an answer because I'm kind of confused.

Comment: Can you be more specific what u r trying to do .. Rule of Thumb : dont create any object unnecessarily unless needed . and more over u r working on C++ where there is no garbage collector unlike other languages.

Comment: @ITion I disagree. OO is about balancing work over different objects. You shouldn't be afraid of using more classes! And in C++ you're not tied to use dynamic allocation, and even when you use it you should rely on smart pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question and your comments it looks like that you are confused with two seemingly conflicting design principles.

- You should encapsulate as much as possible
- You shouldn't hardwire the creation of the needed objects in your implementation.

In your case, you have done right(at least from the visible interfaces) by adhering to the second principle. This is a good example of dependency injection. It is nice to relive the PluginLoader from the responsibility of creating the PluginFactory and the ConflictResolver.

Now, you think that you are violating the 1st principle and this is true to some extend. So, go back and revisit your design problem more closely.

What exactly the PluginLoader need? It just needs the reference to **some** PluginFactory and ConflictResolver object. But it doesn't need to create them by itself. How to solve this problem?

There are two ways I can think of:

- Have another level of abstraction as done in a [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Here
  the complex (or *apparently* complex in your case) building and
  wiring process is moved to a builder object. The main program is not
  bothering about how this is done. It just triggers the building
  process.
- Have another factory that can create the helper objects like
  PluginFactory and ConflictResolver and let the PluginLoader only know
  about the interface of this new factory. The main program can create 
  a concrete instance of this factory and pass on to the PluginBuilder.

By using either of the above ways you can eliminate your conflict with the principle 2.

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is to use a [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) mechanism: you can thus choose the concrete `PluginFactory` and `ConflictResolver` by changing just a string, maybe loaded from a configuration file.

I developed a dependency injection library in C++ named [Wallaroo](http://code.google.com/p/wallaroo/). In your application you may declare your PluginLoader class using this code:

```
REGISTERED_CLASS( PluginLoader, void, void )
{
    ...
private:
    Plug< Logger > logger;
    Plug< PluginFactory > pluginFactory;
    Plug< ConflictResolver > conflictResolver;
};
```

then, you can decide the concrete classes to use and their wiring in an xml file:

```
<catalog>

  <!-- build the objects of your app -->

  <object>
    <name>loader</name>
    <class>PluginLoader</class>
  </object>

  <object>
    <name>logger</name>
    <class>MyConcreteLogger</class>
  </object>

  <object>
    <name>factory</name>
    <class>MyConcretePluginFactory</class>
  </object>

  <object>
    <name>resolver</name>
    <class>MyConcreteResolver</class>
  </object>

  <!-- wiring of the objects: -->

  <relation>
    <source>loader</source>
    <dest>logger</dest>
    <role>logger</role>
  </relation>

  <relation>
    <source>loader</source>
    <dest>factory</dest>
    <role>pluginFactory</role>
  </relation>

  <relation>
    <source>loader</source>
    <dest>resolver</dest>
    <role>conflictResolver</role>
  </relation>

</catalog>
```

or by using this code:

```
catalog.Create( "loader", "PluginLoader" );
catalog.Create( "logger", "MyConcreteLogger" );
catalog.Create( "factory", "MyConcretePluginFactory" );
catalog.Create( "resolver", "MyConcreteResolver" );

wallaroo_within( catalog )
{
    use( "logger" ).as( "logger" ).of( "loader" );
    use( "factory" ).as( "pluginFactory" ).of( "loader" );
    use( "resolver" ).as( "conflictResolver" ).of( "loader" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the PluginLoader class have pointers to those classes. I would forward declare the classes and I wouldn't define the classes anywhere but in the implementation files so that no one else has visibility. That is better encapsulation, plus doing that cuts down on compile time too.

I wouldn't use a raw pointer, but auto_ptr, scoped_ptr or unique_ptr should work.

If you create those objects in the constructor, or even later when first used (lazy construction) then you don't need to pass anything into the constructor and you can drop those parameters.

Edit:

From other comments I see I may have misunderstood your question. If you want to have customizable objects that implement an interface but can be anything underneath then you have to create them at the top level and pass in the interface reference/pointer, like you are doing.

I suppose that you could use a template to "pass" the class type into your object so that it can create those classes for itself. However, using templates would make the class types be fixed at compile time which may not be what you want.

Comment: So, the responsibility to create concrete objects for interfaces falls on the top level?

Comment: @nakiya: Well, explain where else might create those objects?

Comment: Yep, I can't see anywhere else. I wish there was a way in which the `PluginLoader` class can create the objects it uses internally itself. Perhaps by passing `MainClass` as a parameter to the `PluginLoader` constructor - that again would mean there will have to be a way to find out what to create from `MainClass`. I guess I'd rather go with this.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that you are exposing the internal stuff in the constructor for possible customization but not the typical case. If this is correct then one thought is to make these parameters optional and create them inside if not provided.

Answer (score 0):

> ...classes are all interface classes which will be implemented in the application...
>
> ...`PluginFactory` and `ConflictResolver` are only used internally in the
> `PluginLoader` class...

This basically means that even though they are only used internally you have to expose the existance of `PluginFactory` and `ConflictResolver` as you need to have the client implement them, and then pass custom implementations to `PluginLoader` in some way (in this case through constructor).

However the declaration of the named object at the top level (either static or automatic inside `main`) can be avoided (not sure why one would want to do that though) by replacing references with pointers (preferably the smart kind, unique_ptr will be just the tool for the job):

```
class PluginLoader
{
public:
    PluginLoader(
        std::unique_ptr<Logger> logger,
        std::unique_ptr<PluginFactory> plugin_factory,
        std::unique_ptr<ConflictResolver> conflict_resolver
    )
        : logger(std::move(logger))
        , plugin_factory(std::move(plugin_factory))
        , conflict_resolver(std::move(conflict_resolver))
    {
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Logger> logger,
    std::unique_ptr<PluginFactory> plugin_factory,
    std::unique_ptr<ConflictResolver> conflict_resolver
};
```

and create `PluginLoader` like so:

```
PluginLoader plugin_loader(
    std::unique_ptr<CustomLogger>(new CustomLogger(/* ... */))
    std::unique_ptr<CustomPluginFactory>(new CustomPluginFactory(/* ... */))
    std::unique_ptr<CustomConflictResolver>(new CustomConflictResolver(/* ... */))
);
```

where `CustomLogger`, `CustomPluginFactory` and `CustomConflictResolver` are implementations of `Logger`, `PluginFactory` and `ConflictResolver` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

We have used a similar design for an app that uses a dll we create.  The logger is known in the main app and is used in the dll.  However, there are objects that are only used internally to the dll.  I'm still not clear on why they are even part of the interface for the PluginLoader at all if they are only used internally.  Do any parts of the other objects depend on those interfaces externally?

What I'm getting at is why not use factories for both those parameters, PluginFactory, ConflictResolver and not pass them as params at all?

e.g.
     PluginLoader(Logger&);

Then in your implementation

```
 PluginLoader(Logger& logger){
    Factory::PluginFactory::GetInstance().useInstance;// example
    Factory::ConflicResolver::GetInstance().useInstance;// exmaple
 }
```

Or maybe you can elaborate?